# Query data from database then populate table

Tags: php, database, prado

How can I implement this:
I want to create a webpage where I have a table and populate it with some of the fields in my database. The items in my table can be sorted (ascending/descending) by clicking the table header. The items can be selected by row then by clicking it, will direct me to editing the entry. just like the way the tables in phppos was implemented (https://demo.phppointofsale.com/).
I'm using PHP and using prado framework.

Comment: what you have done show some source code

Comment: actually, i used the TScaffoldView of prado. but i dont like it. so i plan of scrapping that idea of mine. so any suggestions would do regarding that matter.